# Is it possible to rename commands in the AWS ElastiCache Redis?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

Normally we can rename/remove redis commands using config file

```
rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52
rename-command CONFIG ""
```

Is this possible in AWS redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple answer:** No this is not possible.

You can find all the parameters that can be configured in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ParameterGroups.Redis.html

Comment: I need to rename FLUSHDB, this mean it is not possible?

Comment: Yes, sadly that is not possible in AWS redis, however Commands like CONFIG is disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can with 5.0.3 version of ElastiCache Redis
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/amazon-elasticache-for-redis-adds-support-for-redis-503-and-the-ability-to-change-redis-command-names/